# Is it possible to do a CNN for classification using both images and and a dataframe using Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, image, conv-neural-network, classification

I am working on a classification problem where I have processed images (greyscale) to make them less noisy and hopefully allow for more success. In addition, I have a dataframe with more statistical properties of the original image/event that the CNN would not be able to gather from the image itself. Is it possible to put both of these data sources into the CNN (images and dataframe)?  Thank you!

I have tried using just images (RGB) with limited success. I am currently using the Tensorflow package, but am open to other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you are trying to push both image tensor and numerical tensor.

Firstly create a model that has 2 input heads, one for processing image data one for numerical data. An example;

```
def forward(self, image_arr, arr):
    conv_out = self.convNet(image_arr)
    concatenated_input = torch.concatenate([conv_out, image_arr])
    last_out = self.main_network(concatenated_input)
    return last_out
```

I gave an example with torch. I suggest that use torch for these detailed requirements.

Shortly, encode image data with CNN, encode numerical data (or don't encode) and concat them, feed to the main model.